# Error with Email to a friend functionality

Tags: magento2, email

I am trying to send an email to a friend for products https://prnt.sc/oujsr5 but getting this error https://prnt.sc/ole1kk.

I am using outlook service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Can you advise on what extension you are using? or are you using the standard magento functionality?

The issue is down to any email client using smtp-mail.outlook.com to send email.

In July, there was a change that disallowed you using a return email address that are not in your list of verified email aliases or connected accounts.

In other words, you can't change the "From" field in emails you send to an anonymous email address.

Comment: then how will the email to friend functionality works. There we are sending an email with customers email address in from field and not the registered email address. I am using Mageplaza SMTP module.

Comment: I would raise a support ticket with them regarding this as they created the module and without physically downloading and implimenting i cannot be 100%

Comment: @DavaGordan. Will this work with default magento email functionlity?

Comment: It works on default magento as you are not changing the from email in the default magento platform

Answer (score 0):

**Override `\Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport` File In Your Custom Module :-**

> **di.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport" type="Vendor\Module\Mail\Transport" />
 </config>
```

> Create **Transport.php** File On This Location `Vendor\Module\Mail\Transport`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Mail;

use Closure;
use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Mageplaza\Smtp\Helper\Data;
use Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Rse\Mail;
use Mageplaza\Smtp\Model\LogFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Zend\Mail\Message;

class Transport extends \Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport
{
    public function __construct(Mail $resourceMail, LogFactory $logFactory, Registry $registry, Data $helper, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::__construct($resourceMail, $logFactory, $registry, $helper, $logger);
    }

    public function aroundSendMessage(
        TransportInterface $subject,
        Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $this->_storeId = $this->registry->registry('mp_smtp_store_id');
        $message = $this->getMessage($subject);
        if ($this->resourceMail->isModuleEnable($this->_storeId) && $message) {
            if ($this->helper->versionCompare('2.2.8')) {
                $message = Message::fromString($message->getRawMessage())->setEncoding('utf-8');
            }
            $message = $this->resourceMail->processMessage($message, $this->_storeId);
            /* Custom code start here */

            foreach ($message->getFrom() as $address) {
                $senderEmail = $address->getEmail();
                $senderName = $address->getName();
            }
            $this->resourceMail->setFromByStore($senderEmail,$senderName);

            /* custom code end here */
            $transport = $this->resourceMail->getTransport($this->_storeId);
            try {
                if (!$this->resourceMail->isDeveloperMode($this->_storeId)) {
                    $transport->send($message);
                }
                if ($this->helper->versionCompare('2.2.8')) {
                    $messageTmp = $this->getMessage($subject);
                    if ($messageTmp && is_object($messageTmp)) {
                        $body = $messageTmp->getBody();
                        if (is_object($body) && $body->isMultiPart()) {
                            $message->setBody($body->getPartContent("0"));
                        }
                    }
                }

                $this->emailLog($message);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->emailLog($message, false);
                throw new MailException(new Phrase($e->getMessage()), $e);
            }
        } else {
            $proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not creating any custom module.

Comment: to resolve this issue, you need to create above files in your custom module

Comment: Which custom module?

Comment: custom module means create new module if you dont want to direct change in Core File....

Comment: For what? Do didnt get my question i guess

Comment: for not sending email issue

Comment: Can u tell me what have you done in your code. Will your code send an email with the address other than registered email address?

Comment: issue generate because $senderEmail Getting Null..